# Fluentbit with Tomcat logs

Tags: tomcat, kubernetes, permissions, logstash, fluent-bit

I am using fluent-bit version 1.4.6 and I am trying to collect logs from a tomcat/logs folder, but I receive:

`[error] [input:tail:tail.0] read error, check permissions`
These files inside the logs folder are all "rw-r-----" (640).

I tried to confirm whether it can read it at all by changing the permissions of a file inside the logs folder and it works, but that does not solve the overall problem.

My question is, is this something that should be set on the tomcat level or it can be done via fluent-bit? Can I start that as a different user?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify  how you deployed fluent-bit.

But yes you can run it as a different user specifying a [SecurityContext](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/) in Kubernetes.

For example:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluent-bit
  namespace: logging
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluent-bit-logging
    version: v1
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: fluent-bit-logging
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: fluent-bit-logging
        version: v1
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        prometheus.io/port: "2020"
        prometheus.io/path: /api/v1/metrics/prometheus
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000  user id that you want to run the containers in the pod as
      containers:
      - name: fluent-bit
        image: fluent/fluent-bit:1.3.11
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 2020
        volumeMounts:
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
        - name: fluent-bit-config
          mountPath: /fluent-bit/etc/
        - name: mnt
          mountPath: /mnt
          readOnly: true
...
```

✌️

Answer (score 1):

### thanks for all the tips, I tried all of them, and it works, but unfortunately, on our deployments it does not as we have some custom users.

What was needed to be done is to set the UMASK as env variable with a value of "111" which would change permissions of the log files so they can be picked up by fluent-bit.